# To which table a given number belogns?

Tags: math

I have this problem, I need to calculate to which table a number belongs.

For example, I need to determine to which table the number 18 belongs.

```
+---+---+ +---+---+ +---+---+ +---+---+ +---+---+
| 1 | 2 | | 5 | 6 | | 9 |10 | |13 |14 | |17 |18 |
+---+---+ +---+---+ +---+---+ +---+---+ +---+---+
| 3 | 4 | | 7 | 8 | | 11| 12| |15 |16 | |19 |20 | 
+---+---+ +---+---+ +---+---+ +---+---+ +---+---+
```

In the example above, the number 18 belongs to the 5th table. How can I calculate the table any number belongs to?, knowing each table can contain only 4 numbers?.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: Well, certainly it's a maths problem, but I asked here because I need to apply its solution to a software I'm developing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide by the size of each table and round up:

```
table_no = ceil(number / 4)
```

Take precaution with integer division in some languages. The same result without conversion to float, using integer division:

```
table_no = (number - 1) / 4 + 1
```